# Weird AJAX error: not getting a response on AJAX call while getting a response when doing the exact call with different values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an admin panel in which I want to update the order status to pending/done with a radio button on each order.

Here is my HTML:

```
<td><form class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="0" checked="checked" data-id="42">Pending</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" data-id="42">Done</label>
</form></td>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var radio = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({url: "functions.php?radio=" + radio + "&id=" + id, success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }});
  });
```

And here is my PHP:

```
if($_GET['radio']) {
    $query = "UPDATE `kvitel` SET `status`= ".$_GET['radio']." WHERE `id`= " . $_GET['id'] . " LIMIT 1";
    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 2;
    }
}
```

When I press on the 'Done' radio button everything works fine, but when I try to press the 'Pending' radio button I get an empty AJAX response and the database does not get updated.

Can anyone help me with this please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if($_GET['radio'])
```

to

```
if(isset($_GET['radio']))
```

If you look `if(variable)` your are checking a boolean, 0 means false so it should not enter in that branch

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this `value="0"`, the `if` statement in `PHP` fails as this becomes `0` which is `false`

```
if($_GET['radio']) { // GET value is 0, this fails.
```

Comment: Fixed it with @quirimmo's answer tx!